# Elasticsearch query ignoring spaces

Tags: elasticsearch

On Elasticsearch how can you query a string attribute ignoring white spaces ?

The scenario is having phone numbers indexed as strings, with different formatings. Querying a phone without spaces, can I get all strings that have that phone (with or without spaces). For example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "Contacts",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "Contacts.ContactValue",
          "query": "261981255"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query would return contacts like: "261981255", "261 981 255", "26 19 81 25 5", etc.

Comment: Not specific to the question (dadoonet covered that), but don't use the filter that way. [A filter that lives outside of the query is a post filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-request-post-filter.html). You want to use it like the link shows (inside of the query) to avoid extra work. Also, `match_all` can just be `"query" : { "match_all" : { } }`.

Comment: @jovin4: did you manage to get a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a specific analyzer which breaks your query into grams.

You can do that by setting un the mapping a search_analyzer for your field.

Comment: Can I get that by applying a default terms analyzer? The analyzer will split the attribute values in terms (grams?), but then will it match to return the records that have a match, while joining all the terms ? Is this an OOTB behaviour? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to reindex your data using a char filter in your analyzer to recognize these patterns and adjust to a desired way.

By this way, all your future queries will be easy to perform if you have a single pattern in entire data.